# how do you strip html tags in textarea input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set up a little web application where you add post-its to a page. It's just a project to help better learn JavaScript/jQuery and it seemed like an appropriate project (I'm new to JS/jQuery).

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/mWaPz/

I found this website: http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/remove-html-tag.php

I implemented the code as so:

> ```
> function stripHTML(){
> var re = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
> for (i=0; i < arguments.length; i++)
> arguments[i].value=arguments[i].value.replace(re, "")
> }
> ```

and it still didnt work.

The problem: I need it so that when somebody inputs text into the textarea, if they input something like this "`<b>Hi</b>`" it would strip the "`<b>`" tag from the input and leave just the text.

If someone could help me out this it would be great.. Thanks!

Comment: from your question what i understand is that you also want to delete the contents of the tags?

Comment: @DanBarzilay _it would strip the "<b>" tag from the input and leave just the text._

Comment: @DanBarzilay thats exactly what i mean

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have three issues: One is that the method is not returning properly (that's the fault of whoever wrote it). Next is that you are defining the method within `$(document).ready()`, so it is not able to be found (at least in Chrome). Third, you are not calling it the right way (`onSubmit` will never be used here).

I've used @Joao's method (so you should upvote his answer) and used this method, moved outside of the `ready()` function:

```
function stripHTML(str){
  var strippedText = $("<div/>").html(str).text();
  return strippedText;
}​
```

And also called it here:

```
var post = stripHTML($(".text_input").val())
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ee3MH/

Comment: that wouldn't delete the contents of a tag

Comment: @eric your fiddle is actually coming up with an error when i add your changes.. here is the full code with you add-ons: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=j0STwjAA

Comment: For some reason you have a bad character (`?` when shown in ASCII) before your `</script>` tag, one before your `</style>` tag, and perhaps some others. Once I removed these, I ran the entire script you pasted with no problems. (Link: [http://pastebin.com/qASL40dz](http://pastebin.com/qASL40dz))

Comment: yup, found the problem. you're the man! thank you so much @Eric

Comment: Although this seems to be the most popular answer for stripping HTML tags in JavaScript (i.e. using the browser engine), bear in mind that in IE8 `innerText` and `$.text()` will not respect newlines `\r\n`, and as a result it can seriously mess with the content of a textarea.

Comment: This is not actually a guaranteed method. It will only strip one layer of tags and can call any embedded javascript.   Test with onkeyup and <script>alert(1)</script>  and then add a <script> to the beginning. It will call the script before returning.  Especially on places that perform the assumptions on end tags.

Answer (score 14):

```
var textAreaValue = "text <br /> more text";
var strippedText = $("<div/>").html(textAreaValue).text();​
```

And here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xheSt/).

Comment: how would i implement that in my website app?

Comment: that wouldn't delete the contents of a tag

Comment: @DanBarzilay: Indeed, OP asked for that: *it would strip the "<b>" tag from the input and leave just the text*.

Comment: and that was after : "Problam:"... read it all before commenting and look in the comments i asked him exactly that

Comment: @DanBarzilay: I don't think that's what OP wants, it doesn't make much sense to remove actual content from the text area. He actually accepted an answer that uses this strategy.

Comment: i saw that's wierd because in the comments he said that he wants the inner content also deleted..

Comment: @DanBarzilay: Yes, the comment and the actual question are somewhat contradictory :-).

Comment: ahaha sorry about the mix-up!

Answer (score 7):

```
function stripHTML(text){
   var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
   return text.replace(regex, "");
}
// USE: var str = stripHTML('<b>test</b>');
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/pisabev/eJzfw/3/

Comment: if you could do me a favor and implement that in jsfiddle, i'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: When I add <script></script> it fails ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery .text function, though it will rather escape the html than strip it:

```
$(".myTxtBox").text("<b>this text will be displayed, even the b tag.");
```

Answer (score 0):

No one successfully answered this question in accordance with the OP's request, in that the inner tags would be completely removed from the input, not just the tags themselves; so, here's an answer that will do precisely that ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utH47/)):

```
var input = "This is <b>not</b>a successful test";
var output = $("<div/>").html(input).children().remove().end().text()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("textarea.text_input").on('keyup', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mWaPz/1/)