# Removing HTML tags from a string and keeping ":" (colon)

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Is there a way to remove html from a string in Javascript and keep the : (colon)

I have gone through [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) and [how do you strip html tags in textarea input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022614/how-do-you-strip-html-tags-in-textarea-input) and some similar questions on SO, but unable to find the right solution.

For e.g. `"Something here<div> content</div>"` should give `"Something here content"`
and `"Something here :)"` should give `"Something here :)"`

The offered solutions in other problems help in stripping the HTML content but also strip smileys.

**EDIT**: Before mentioning solutions which would strip smileys from the text, please note that I need this in improving my chat engine solution at www.chesshunt.com. Where currently I am stripping the HTML tags along with the smileys

My current code

```
function strip(html) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried that didn't work as expected.

Comment: @jrummel I have tried a lot of things.. jquery .text() as well as some other solutions based on regex

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/fkDUk/

Comment: That [very first SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) you linked to works **just fine** http://jsfiddle.net/QXBZe/ It doesn't make sense that HTML stripping would ever remove a text colon or semicolon.

Comment: @undefined the solution provided in jsfiddle would not work for any other html tag other than <div>

Comment: @Alex I already mentioned my problem. If you wish to see the problem in action, check out the chat implementation in my project www.chesshunt.com Just that you could not help me doesn't mean that the question doesnt mean any sense

Comment: @Anshu Why do you think so? http://jsfiddle.net/KZM2S/

Comment: @Anshu Well then maybe you should post the code you are currently using that is acting up? Because you already linked to solutions that should be working for this task. Therefore, it's _your code_ that has an error that we will happily help you find. But we probably wont be signing up on your website just so we can sift through your whole codebase and find a small eror in a tiny part of it. Just post the code you are currently using to do this escaping.

Comment: `:` is a colon. `;` is a semicolon. Just saying...

Comment: @stealthyninja Thanks I edited the question. Its a colon

Comment: Apparently you've replaced smiley characters by HTML `<img>` tags before stripping HTML. You should do it the other way round 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to disagree with your statement that "The offered solutions in other problems help in stripping the html content but also strip smileys."

Here is an example based on your links: http://jsfiddle.net/be8gz/

Comment: I really have no idea.. how it is not working for me. Probably I have been banging my head somewhere else.

Comment: @Anshu the issue might be upstream with your html string.

Comment: Aww, it breaks one of my favourite emoticons: >_<

Comment: Wow, @Christophe You are Amazing! This issue took a lot of time. But Your answer is very useful to me. You saved me.

Thank you So Much

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the content is in another container just use the .text() function:

```
$('#some_container').text();
```

Comment: I already mentioned I have tried it. It would not retain smileys and I need that

Answer (score 2):

You could create an element using

```
var element = document.createNode('<div>'+yourString+'</div>');
```

and then get the textContent (for all browsers except IE) or innerText.

EDIT : Arg, there wasn't jQuery initially in the tags... So it's possible to use

```
var stripped = $('<div>'+yourString+'</div>').text();
```

[DEMONSTRATION (keeping the smiley)](http://jsfiddle.net/8V6p4/)

Comment: This is the Best Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjaH6/)

```
    var myStr = "Something here<div> content</div>";    
    var myRegEx = /<\/?[^<>]*\/?>/gim;
     var result = myStr.split(myRegEx).join("");
```

OR

```
    result = myStr.replace(/<\/?[^<>]*\/?>/gim, "");

​
```

Comment: Most likely because [regex is the wrong tool to parse HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex should do the job

```
var string = "Something here<div> content</div> :)";
alert(string.replace(/<([^>]+)>.*?<\/\1>/g,''));​
```

Comment: not sure why this was down voted, it does the job....

Comment: I am using this expression and I never faced problem. I collect data from different sites feed

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you want to keep the smileys or not.  Based on the example in your question I must assume you want to keep the smileys, but get rid of any html tags.  I think a regex like this would work:

```
pattern = /<.*?>/g;
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/ywTDk/).