# JQuery - serialize form and get rid of possible html tags inside inputs

Tags: jquery, html, serialization, tags

I would like to know if that could be possible **to get rid of possible html tags inserted** by someone in my html inputs, before sending this to the server **using the serialize method of JQuery.**

I know how I could do that without using the serialize method, as an example,simply by using the .text() method, like that:

```
var superVariable =$("<h1>lalala<span>dededeedede</span><lilili/h1>");

console.log(superVariable.text());

//would simply return lalaladededeededelilili
```

But I simply don't know how to achieve this kind of result with the serialize method, I know I can strip tags easily on the server side with PHP in this case, but I wanted to do this as well on the client side, before sending the datas.

I could as well stop using the serialize() method and get rid of all the possible html tags one by one on each inputs, but I would like to see If this is possible to achieve the same result while keeping the serialize() method.

EDIT: Following the comment of Rory

Which kind of checking should I accomplish on the client side ?

- Inputs required or not.
- max-length min length.
- trimming values to get rid of blank spaces.

And on the server side, still the same checking as JS can be disabled plus all the checking to delete potiental html inserted by users ?

Am I right ?

Comment: I would suggest you do that kind of validation server side. Relying on JS to filter out potential security issues such as injected HTML is asking for trouble.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok I thought that would be better to do almost all the checkings on both sides. At the moment, what I do on the client side is, ensuring some required inputs aren't empty, I as well check the max length of these ones, lastly I trim as well all blank spaces. Is It enough for the checking on the client side, before sending datas to the server ? I'll get rid of potential inserted HTML tags only there so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, Azuk.  Check all of those things on the client and server since the JavaScript on the client can be disabled.   I would also validate input types (Integer, DateTime, String) if that matters to your application.

Also, you can strip HTML from text using Regex in JavaScript:

```
function stripHTML(text){
   var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
   return text.replace(regex, "");
}
// USE: var str = stripHTML('<b>test</b>');
```

This was discussed here:
[how do you strip html tags in textarea input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022614/how-do-you-strip-html-tags-in-textarea-input)