# Can't get exact print out result from HTML textarea

Tags: html, forms, richtextbox

I am creating a form for medical prescription. Here one of the `textarea` field name is `new prescription`. Doctor will insert value here like

```
1. medicine-l
   1+1+1
2. medicine-2
   1+0+1
```

But while I print out the prescription this `new prescription` field shows it's value like

```
1.medicine-1 1+1+1 2.medicine-2 1+0+1
```

But I want to printout the value of `new prescription` just like how doctor inserted.

How can I do it? Anybody Help Please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you strip html tags in textarea input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022614/how-do-you-strip-html-tags-in-textarea-input)

Comment: This is not asking how to strip tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line breaks are actually preserved untill you print the text out. HTML doesn't doesn't detect the line breaks in the text.

Try this for JS:

```
textAreaText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

[How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

Try this for PHP :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the [CSS property `white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

**Example:**

```css
.textarea-class {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Consult [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for a very nice overview if the various options, but it seems like you want either `pre` (just as it is), `pre-wrap` (maintains spacing and line breaks, but wraps), or even `pre-line` (maintains line breaks but not spacing, and wraps).

You’ll want to put this in [your print stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing).